# ASP.NET Web API 2 authentication for Windows Service

Tags: oauth-2.0, windows-services, asp.net-web-api2

I have developed an API using ASP.NET Web API 2 to be consumed by applications in my domain. I want to secure the access to the API endpoints. I've decided to use the OAuth token based token authentication for mobile app clients and web app clients.

However there are some non-interactive windows service clients that need to consume the API. I do not want to store login credentials to get a token in the service config, however a Windows authentication suits this type of client.

Is it possible to use a hybrid - windows and token-based authentication in ASP.NET WebApi? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Windows authentication service from Identityserver might be a good solution for your problem

You can find more information on : [WindowsAuthentication repo](https://github.com/IdentityServer/WindowsAuthentication)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Identity Server and it's Windows Authentication sample, I consider myself a newbie with Identity Server and looking forward to learning more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to break up the API into two. One for normal OAuth based access and the other with specific resources using Windows authentication to be consumed by non-interactive windows service clients.